# SFML button triggers twice

Tags: c++, button, sfml

I'm using SFML to write game and I got small problem with my button. Here is function I use to check if button is clicked:

```
bool InputManager::isSpriteClicked(sf::Sprite object, sf::Mouse::Button button, sf::RenderWindow &window) {

    if (sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(button)) {
        sf::IntRect rect(object.getPosition().x, object.getPosition().y,
            object.getGlobalBounds().width, object.getGlobalBounds().height);
        if (rect.contains(sf::Mouse::getPosition(window))) {
            return true;            
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

It works almost fine, yet sometimes once I press this button, action is trigerred twice, like I double click it, even tho I didnt even release it yet. I tried to involve  `sf::Event::MouseButtonReleased` but It actually wasnt helping too. What I want to achieve is of course just 1 action per 1 button press/release/whatever.

Here is example of my `GameLoop` if its needed

```
void GameState::handleUserInput() {
    sf::Event evnt;
    while (this->m_data->window.pollEvent(evnt)) {      

        if (this->m_data->input.isSpriteClicked(this->m_rollButton, sf::Mouse::Left, this->m_data->window)) {           
            m_gameEngine.startTurn(m_gameStatusBox);
        }
}

void GameState::update(sf::Time dt) {
    m_gameEngine.getActivePlayer().move(dt); 
}

void GameState::draw() {
    this->m_data->window.display(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

```
    if (event.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed)
```

[Long story](https://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=15275.0) By the way, it's second link in google....

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing two different approaches to manage user input

- Input by **events**: used to manage those things that happen once and you want to be notified
- **Real time** input: basically, poll repeatedly for input status (in this case, the mouse)

The general rule:

```
    if (sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Left))
        // WHILE the left mouse button is being pressed, do something 
    if (event.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed)
        // WHEN the left mouse button has been pressed, do something
```

If you want to learn more, i recommend you to read [this](http://pdf.th7.cn/down/files/1312/SFML%20Game%20Development.pdf#p100) chapter (or better, the whole book) about SFML game dev.